# How can I increase Google Earth plug-in cache for loading overlays?

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

I have a lot of hi-res ground overlays on the plug-in version of GE.
Is there any way I increase the amount of memory Google Earth plug-in uses for cache for loading these image overlays?

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the memory to the plugin is not the correct way to go about this. The thing is (ultimately) running in a web browser. If the KML data is not stored locally, then the user has to download your entire overlay all at once, which could take a while.

The correct approach is to break your large ground overlay into several small tiles that can be loaded individually when needed. E.g., If your overlay covers an entire state, don't load the tiles that are out of the user's view. Google calls overlays that follow this paradigm "Super Overlays"

More information on Super Overlays and how to use them with Google Earth is available [here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_21tutorial#superoverlays).

Comment: Yrs. I've considered them, but they require the user to slice and dice the images up

Comment: Yes, but there are a whole host of utilities to do this for you. Google "Superoverlay creator Google Earth"

Comment: +1 Good answer, this is the correct way to handle large image overlays. The first sentence in the question is key here. However the caching can still be an issue, especially with DAE files.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way within the API itself to increase the cache size available to the plugin. Indeed I don't think the plugin has any documented configurable system settings at all.

The only possible exception I have come across are various undocumented registry settings in various Windows OSs that allow some things to be configured (such as forcing OpenGL or DirectX rendering) but other than that I don't think there is any way to do this, sorry.

Comment: Just add your name to the list - http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=243 - it was suggested by me in 2009.